# Can anyone identify this component? Please help me

Tags: components, identification

[image: MXAB SAYB]

Can anyone identify this componenet and can anyone find datasheet

Comment: It sometimes helps if you can elaborate on the expected function, surrounding parts.

Comment: @EmirCbn Hi! Take a look at our [guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710/1240) for asking component identification  questions. Expanding the question a bit would make it easier for others to find it and benefit from the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a VSSOP [LM5008](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5008.pdf) switching regulator.

The datasheet shows the markings on Addendum Page-1.

Here’s a random image (that actually matches your lot number), that Google pulled from [Aliexpress](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.aliexpress.com/item/32706134408.html):

[image: image of part]